# Why doesn't JSON data load immediately in my HTML page?

Tags: jquery, json, angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

This is my controller, that takes JSON data to Wordpress :

```
app.controller('AboutController', function($scope, $http) {

$scope.device=device;
var page_id = 2;

$.ajax({
        url: 'http://davidemilone.com/provawp/?json=get_page&page_id='+page_id+'&callback=?',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {

                $scope.page=data.page;
                console.log("contenuto" + $scope.page.content);
        }
});
});
```

Now, this is my HTML page:

```
<ons-page ng-controller="AboutController" >
  <ons-toolbar modifier="opacity">
    <div class="left">
      <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggle()"><ons-icon icon="ion-navicon-round" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon></ons-toolbar-button>
    </div>
    <div class="center">{{page.title}}</div>
  </ons-toolbar>

  <div class="app-page-content">
    <p class="page-content" ng-bind-html="page.content"></p>
  </div>
```

**Why data doesn't load immediately**, it loads only after I click back or when carousel auto slide; what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using Angular's own tools (e.g. `$http` service) to comunicate with the server, so the framework doesn't know that the data has changed.

To let Angular know that something on `$scope` has changed in non-angular way, you should run `$scope.$apply();` after you assign the new data.

*(To explain the "clicking outside" part: it simply triggers the digest loop - same result as `$apply()`, that's why the value was updating then)*

**It would be preferable to use $http service** though. I can see you've already injected it into the controller, so it may be a simple mistake, that you used jQuery's ajax function insted. (see [Angular docs for $http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#general-usage) for details)

```
app.controller('AboutController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.device=device;
    var page_id = 2;

    var url = 'http://davidemilone.com/provawp/?json=get_page&page_id='+page_id+'&callback=?';
    $http.jsonp(url).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.data);
        $scope.page = response.data.page;
    });

});
```

Comment: How to get a single page with angular in the same way of jquery?

Comment: @pinostack I updated the answer with the code sample. You can `console.log` the response returned to be sure what's the exact format of it (I'm not sure if the response body is not keept in `response.data` in this case ;) )

Comment: howewer with $scope.$apply() it works perfectly; thanks a lot for the support; I will wait your answer for $http request single page.

Comment: the result is this Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < at http://.........com/provawp/sample-page/:1 
Note: we have already a plugin json installed in wordpress and the link to request data is http://davidemilone.com/provawp/api/get_page/?page_id=2;

Comment: It looks like a typo somewhere. Make sure you made is exactly as in the docs (I also tried to be thorough, but it's always better to skip the intermediator and rely directly on the source of documentation ;) )

Comment: sorry but now No longer works, even as before ...why this?

Comment: It really should work. But at this moment I don't know how does your code looks after implementign changes.

Comment: There was a problem with lib, but now it's seems all ok..thanks for the support